# How to set endpoint for java AmazonS3 client?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, cloud, minio

I have a cloud store,  made our devops engineers. They gave me an address of its balancer: https://bla-bla-bla.company.com:9000, access-key: 1234567, secret-key: 7654321, bucket-name: bucketName.
Using minio client I can create a client like this:

```
MinioClient.builder()
          .endpoint("https://bla-bla-bla.company.com:9000")
          .credentials("1234567", "7654321")
          .build();
```

But AmazonS3 client works like this:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("1234567", "7654321");

return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
    .standard()
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
    .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2) 
    .build();
```

How to set my endpoint to it?

Comment: what was the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()

```
                    .withEndpointConfiguration(
                            new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(                                        "your_endpoint", "region"))

                    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                    .build();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).